# UI Testing Failure - Application for "bakBarButtonItem" Button is not frontmost

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

While using **Xcode Server** I faced an issue like the following:

> UI Testing Failure - Application for "bakBarButtonItem" Button is not frontmost

What this error mean? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your application is not in the foreground at the time that you tried to interact with the back bar button item.

This could be because the application has crashed, it has been sent to the background, or because a system alert or other system-level UI has interrupted your application.